# Query for showing the Passers from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Student_ID     | First_Name | Last_Name | Examination_date | Exam_grade
               |            |           |                  |
    12345      |    John    |     Doe   |     12/01/2019   |     5
    67890      |    Johny   |    Bravo  |     12/02/2019   |     7
    09876      |    Johnny  |     Boy   |     12/02/2019   |     3
```

Hello Good day, I just want to show only the students who passed the exam, that has a minimum grade of 5 above. Thank you so much

here's my query

```
$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_admission where exam_grade > 5");
```

Comment: What is the difference (if any) between passing the exam and having a minimum grade of 5 or above?

Comment: The examinee must have the minimum of passing grade as 5 and above

Comment: Can there be multiple exam attempts?  Or, would each student have at most only a single test entry?

Comment: I would not expect to see a 2 in such a query. Presumably you would agree that that seems a little perverse?

Comment: No, they only take the exam once.

Comment: Use this query SELECT * FROM tbl_admission where exam_grade >= 5

Comment: well done, I just put a equals(=). Thank you so much :)

Comment: use `BETWEEN  5 AND 9999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For having grade 5 or above you should use `>=` in your query .

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admission where exam_grade >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

use this condition - `where exam_grade >= 5`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admission where exam_grade >= 5
```